# How to Render or Convert HTML code to Plain Text generated from wysiwyg editor

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I used a wysiwyg editor (CKEditor) in my web application to provide a basic word processor for the user. I tried to save the output of that CKEditor to pdf document.
I can now generate pdf document but the problem is the output of from CKEditor is in HTML code and it is getting published in pdf as it is. 
I want to publish that pdf document as seen in CKEditor, but I dont want those HTML tags in the pdf. Is there any libraries in Java to render or convert that html code to the plain text by eliminating those html tags but retaining their effect i.e. if HTML code has **This is Bold** then pdf should be saved as **This is Bold** not like
  `<b>` This is Bold`</b>`

Comment: What do you mean by?
> if HTML code has **This is Bold** then pdf should be saved as **This is Bold** not like **This is Bold**

Comment: oh no .. the editor on this page converted that html code . . Sorry !
Actually that last "This is Bold" in in bold tag

Comment: Ah ok. Try installing something like CutePDF and opening up the html file in a browser and printing using the CutePDF printer

Comment: I am developing a web application. Generating PDF from the users input in CKEditor is one of the function of the web application.

Comment: My bad !! Din't read through the question fully

Comment: @shyam : any suggestion for converting html code to plain text ?

Comment: Are you using something like this? http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=55

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library to convert the HTML from ckeditor to PDF. There are quite a few options that will convert HTML to PDF. This flying-saucer project is one a good one: https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/.

Comment: i am currently using itext and its working just fine. but the problem is it is converting html to pdf with its tags like `<b>` `<i>` etc. i want to remove these tags

Comment: The flying saucer project I mentioned uses iText underneath to generate the PDF, it should simplify things for you by hiding some of the iText details. It allows you to provide HTML & CSS as input and will render PDF based on the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) is a pretty popular library for converting HTML to PDF. However be mindful of the licensing associated with the version of iText you use if you do choose to use their library.